# how can I stop chart line using c# and report view

Tags: c#, charts, linechart

how  can I stop the line of value in a chart line using c# and report view (windows forms) ?

I want my chart just stop if my value = 0, like this example

[Chart line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLkfp.jpg)

In this example, the same value being 0 is still shown in my graph, I want it to be equal to 0 when this value is just stopped at this point.

I am using reportviewer with rdlc inside, can someone help me?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

i solved my problem changing my return 0.0 to double.NaN.